# What's the difference between a certstore and a keystore?

Tags: certificate, openssl, keystore

I'm specifically using openssl in RHEL.

What's the difference between a certstore and a keystore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are exactly the same thing.  However, it is keytool terminology, not openssl terminology.  Either way, it stores certificates (such as a list of trusted CA certificates, or your certificates), and private keys as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

A key store stores keys which are used for signing and a cert store stores signed certs?

Comment: Are you attempting to ask a question or unsure about your answer?